# What's the meaning of "elude" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Executive presence further eludes professionals of color because
>   they’re not likely to get feedback on their “presentation of self.”

I searched the online dictionaries and found the definitions below for the verb [elude](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/elude):

- to avoid someone or something
- If something eludes you, you do not succeed in achieving it

However I cann't understand meaning of the sentence.

So could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text is here:

> Executive presence further **eludes** professionals of color because
>   they’re not likely to get feedback on their “presentation of self.”
>   Qualitative fi ndings affi rm that their superiors, most of whom are
>   white, hesitate to call attention to gravitas shortfalls or
>   communication blunders for fear of coming across as racially
>   insensitive or discriminatory. While sponsors might close this gap by
>   specifi cally addressing EP issues with their high potentials, CTI’s
>   2012 research shows that professionals of color are much less likely
>   to have a sponsor than Caucasians (8% versus 13%).4 When they do get
>   feedback, they’re unclear about how to act on it, particularly if they
>   were born outside the United States. This is a serious problem for
>   corporations that need local expertise to expand their infl uence in
>   global markets.

https://hbr.org/2014/01/cracking-the-code-that-stalls-multicultural-professionals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second bullet-point from the definition you quote explains the meaning in this context:

> If something eludes you, you do not succeed in achieving it

Rephrasing the original sentence using this definition, and separating the two connected clauses for clarity:

> Professionals of color often **do not succeed in achieving** executive presence.  This is because they are not likely to get feedback on their "presentation of self."

Some of the phrases are a big jargony - for example, "executive presence" is a way of saying "acting like a business leader."  I'll try to simplify it a bit more (and bring in some information from your fuller excerpt):

> Professionals of color often **do not succeed in achieving** behavior typical of senior leadership.  This is because their superiors, most of whom are white, are afraid of appearing racially insensitive by criticizing the communication style of minority employees.